# How to use the PDO connection work in the class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using class to do all the database related stuff. Inside a config file contains a class that has a 'Connect' function to establish connection to the database. I have created a connection file which contains information to connect to database. Now for to retrieve the data from the specific table I called the same class and 'Query' function. But in Query function, I need $conn of Connect function. I am little bit weak in object oriented. Can anybody guide me how can I make this work. I have included my files config.php, connection.php and index.php files below.

```
config.php page

<?php
class DBConnection{
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function Connect(){
        try {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->server_name.';dbname='.$this->db,$this->user, $this->pass); 
            $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    static public function Query($sql){
        return $conn->prepare($sql);
    }
}

connection.php page

<?php
require_once('config');

$default=array(
    'DB_SERVER'=>'Localhost',
    'DB_USER'=>'root',
    'DB_PASS'=>'',
    'DB_NAME'=>'hqe'    
    );

$m_db = new DBConnection();
$m_db->server_name=$default['DB_SERVER'];
$m_db->user=$default['DB_USER'];
$m_db->pass=$default['DB_PASS'];
$m_db->db=$default['DB_NAME'];

$m_db->Connect();

index.php page 

<?php
include("connection.php");
$usr = DBConnection::Query("Select id, first_name, last_name from tbl_user");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Connect()` is a member function, while  `Query($sql)` is a static function. I would suggest to define both the same way, either as member or as static.

Next `$conn` needs to be accessible from both methods, so make it a class variable instead a local variable in `Connect()`.

Here is a version without static functions/variables:

```
<?php
class DBConnection{

    private $conn;

    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function Connect(){
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hqe', 'root', ''); 
            $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function Query($sql){
        return $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the member variable is accessed using `$this`. Further you need an object of the class to call `Query()`. Something like:

```
$c = new DBConnection();
$c->Query("Select id, first_name, last_name from tbl_user");
```

Here is a version where all is defined as static:

```
<?php
class DBConnection{

    private static $conn;

    public function __construct(){
    }
    public static function Connect(){
        try {
            self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hqe', 'root', ''); 
            self::$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    static public function Query($sql){
        return self::$conn->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the static variable is accessed using `self::`.

Comment: I have tried defining private $conn . But it didnot work.

Comment: I passed the database name, username and password from connection file to config.php

Comment: again: you are declaring $conn as local variable, that's why it is not accessible in other methods.